# How to keep certain folders and delete rest in Unix

Tags: unix, find, rm, rmdir

I have around 10 folders and I am trying to keep only few subfolders under these and delete the rest.

Example: I have

```
A/1
A/2
A/3 
A/4

B/1
B/4
B/5
B/6
```

I am trying to keep only the folder 1 and 4 under each parent folder A and B. I am using `find -type d -name 2 -exec rm -rf {} \;` to find and delete each folder.

Is there any unix command to just keep the folder 1 and 4 and delete the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Tell find exactly what you are looking for;

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d -name "[^14]" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Excluding directories 1 and 4, at the child level, find the other directories and delete them.

Comment: I tried this command to check and it is not returning anything.

find . -mindepth 2 -type d -name "[^14]" -print

Comment: Very odd. On my install I get the exact results you requested. Unless your directories are not numeric...

Answer (score 1):

AIG's idea to exclude is probably correct, but the way to exclude with find is with the -o (or) operator, which stops if what came before is true and continues otherwise:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type d -name 1 -o -name 4 -o -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this works for posix compliant systems:

```
find . -type d -links 2 \! \( \( -name 1 \) -o \( -name 4 \) \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

This includes only child directories and excludes directories named 1 or 4.

Answer (score 0):

Using just glob

```
$ rm -rf [AB]/[^14]
```